# With Flask SQLalchemy, can you filter a query by unbound method?

Tags: python, methods, filter, sqlalchemy

In my Flask python application, I have several interconnected objects, each with it's own `is_active` toggle to virtually delete the record. When that happens for one record, I want the logical delete to take with it whatever related objects it has. This is how I want to control whether content is published or not in the application.

Since there are other considerations that could factor in besides the relevant `is_active` fields, I have a method defined in each of the models that looks something like:

```
def is_published(self):
    """
        Considers all needed criteria for visibility on the website,
        returning a boolean to reflect current publication status
    """
    if self.is_active and self.member.active and self.published_on:
        return True
    return False
```

where `member` is a relationship defined through a foreign key. So essentially, this record should only be visible if (a) it is active, (b) the member who owns it is active, and (c) it has a publication date defined, replacing the initial null value.

Later, when I want to query a list of all of these published records, I can do something like:

```
articles = ArticleModel.query\
    .join(MemberModel, MemberModel.id==ArticleModel.member_id)\
    .filter(ArticleModel.is_active==True)\
    .filter(ArticleModel.published_on!=None)\
    .filter(MemberModel.active==True)\
    .order_by(desc(ArticleModel.modified_at))\
    .all()
```

This works, but if I want to change the definition for "published" later, I have to find all of the instances of this criteria and make adjustments. I would much rather reference that model's method (or some other central place for that complex criteria).

I want to know if I can set up a query to do something like this:

```
articles = ArticleModel.query\
    .join(MemberModel, MemberModel.id==ArticleModel.member_id)\
    .filter(ArticleModel.is_published()==True)\
    .order_by(desc(ArticleModel.modified_at))\
    .all()
```

Python doesn't like that filter line, returning an error: `TypeError: unbound method is_published() must be called with ArticleModel instance as first argument (got nothing instead)`.

**Is there a way to set multiple filters in one place for a particular model and reference that in the query?**

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using a hybrid property ([docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/mapped_sql_expr.html) and [more docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/orm/extensions/hybrid.html))?

**EDIT**:
Below is a [code example](https://github.com/Freevle/Freevle/blob/project-hiroshima/freevle/blueprints/cms/models.py#L42) (not a very good use case, though). It adds `self.title` as a fall back for `self.short_title`.

```
class SomeModel(db.Model):
    # init blabla
    ...

    @hybrid_property
    def short_title(self):
        return self._short_title if self._short_title is not None else self.title

    @short_title.expression
    def short_title(self):
        return db.case(
            [(Category._short_title == None, Category.title)],
            else_=Category._short_title
        )

    @short_title.setter
    def short_title(self, short_title):
        self._short_title = short_title
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. The hybrid method is allowing me to construct a query that doesn't choke, although I'm having some difficulty getting the correct set of records returned. Promising, though.

Comment: I can't get this to work. Turning `is_published()` into a hybrid property results in an error ("'bool' object is not callable"). Using hybrid method doesn't error but the resulting query does not differentiate between records. The resulting query includes a WHERE clause of 0 or 1.

Comment: The "'bool' object is not callable" is because I was referencing the property as `is_published()` instead of `is_published`, but the resulting query is the same: ... FROM table_name **WHERE 1** ORDER BY ...

Comment: Debugging attempts aside, I made two adjustments to the code above:

1) Added two lines before the `def is_published(self)` line in the model:
    `from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_method, hybrid_property`
    `@hybrid_property`

2) Replaced the join and three filters in the `articles` query with:
    `.filter(ArticleModel.is_published)\`

The resulting query either has a WHERE 0 or WHERE 1 as the generated SQL. I can provide more code, if needed, but not until tomorrow.